# Hartshorne "Algebraic Geometry" theorem 8.15

Tags: algebraic-geometry

The theorem $8.15$(p.177) from the Hartshorne's book "Algebraic Geometry" says:

> " Let $X$ be an irreducible separated scheme of finite type over an algebraically closed field $k$. Then $\Omega_{X/k}$ is a locally free sheaf of rank $n= \dim \ X$ iff $X$ is nonsingular variety over $k$."

I can't understand where does we use the condition that $X$ is separated.

Comment: I doubt that this is needed. After all, we may reduce to the affine case, since both statements are local on $X$. Hartshorne's book is full with imprecise assumptions. Better consult other books (EGA, Liu, Görtz-Wedhorn, Bosch, ...).

Comment: @MartinBrandenburg: Being nonsingular is certainly local, but being a variety is not.

Comment: Ah, ok, but it becomes true when we just omit the word "variety". For details, see Matt's answer.

Answer (score 10):

Hartshorne's *definition* of variety is an integral separated scheme over $k$.
From the assumption on $\Omega_{X/k}$ he can deduce that $X$ is reduced, and since he assumes $X$ separable, he can then deduce that it is integral.  But the assumption on $\Omega_{X/k}$ can't give that $X$ is separated.  Thus he has to *assume* this in order to conclude that $X$ is a variety.  (The fact that it is non-singular then follows from the assumption on $\Omega_{X/k}$.)

If he had worked with a more expansive definition of variety, one that allowed non-separated objects (e.g. what Mumford calls a *pre-variety* in the *Red Book*), then he wouldn't need the separated assumption.